# Exceptuar resultados en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT ItemCode,ItemName from oitm where ItemCode LIKE 'PRT%'
```

Lo que busco es cómo hacer para que me devuelva los resultados que no inicien con PRT en SqlServer uso except, aquí traté con not in y con != pero no tuve éxito espero me puedan ayudar.

Gracias.

Comment: Prueba con `NOT LIKE 'PRT%'`

Comment: Alv, justo lo que ocupaba, te agradezco amigo

Answer (score 4):

Lo puedes solucionar con el operador lógico en SQL llamado "NOT LIKE"

Aquí el ejemplo con tu código:

```
"SELECT ItemCode,ItemName FROM oitm WHERE ItemCode NOT LIKE 'PRT%'"
```

El símbolo de porcentaje "%" (llamado comodín en SQL) funciona en "NOT LIKE" tal cual como se maneja en "LIKE".

Answer (score 0):

También lo puedes hacer mediante RLIKE o RGEXP de varias manera.

**1. `SELECT ItemCode,ItemName FROM oitm WHERE ItemCode NOT RLIKE 'PRT*'`**

**2. `SELECT ItemCode,ItemName FROM oitm WHERE ItemCode RLIKE '[^P][^R][^T]*'`**

**3. `SELECT ItemCode,ItemName FROM oitm WHERE ItemCode NOT RGEXP 'PRT*'`**

**4. `SELECT ItemCode,ItemName FROM oitm WHERE ItemCode RGEXP '[^P][^R][^T]*'`**

Aqui te dejo algunas cosas que se puede con RLIKE o hacer mas potentes que con LIKE.

```
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|PATRÓN       | LO QUE COINCIDE CON EL PATRÓN                                      |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  *          | Cero o más instancias de string que lo preceda                     | 
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  +          | Una o más instancias de strings que lo preceden                    |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  .          | Cualquier personaje                                                |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  ?          | Coincide con cero o una instancia de las strings que lo preceden.  |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  ^          | Comienza (^) coincide con el comienzo de la string                 |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  $          | Fin de string                                                      |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  [a B C]    | Cualquier carácter que aparezca entre corchetes.                   |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  [^ abc]    | Cualquier carácter que no figure entre corchetes.                  |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  [ARIZONA]  | Coincidir con cualquier letra mayúscula.                           |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  [Arizona]  | Coincidir con cualquier letra minúscula.                           |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  [0-9]      | Coincidir con cualquier dígito del 0 al 9.                         |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  [[: <:]]   | Coincide con el comienzo de las palabras.                          |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  [[:>:]]    | Coincide con el final de las palabras.                             |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  [:clase:]  | Coincide con una clase de carácter, es decir, [: alpha:] para que  |
|             | coincida con letras, [: espacio:] para que coincida con el espacio |
|             | en blanco, [: punct:] coincide con las puntuaciones y [: upper:]   |
|             | para las letras de clase superior.                                 |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
| p1 | p2 | p3|   Alternancia; coincide con cualquiera de los patrones p1, p2 o p3 |  
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  {norte}    |  n instancias del elemento anterior.                               |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  {Minnesota}| m hasta n instancias del elemento precedente.                      |
|_____________|____________________________________________________________________|
```

Lo saque todo de esta pagina : https://es.acervolima.com/operador-rlike-en-mysql/